# Is IBM MQ8 compatible with JBoss EAP 7.1?

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

I searched for this pretty much everywhere in google and stack overflow.

We are in a project that was using JBoss EAP 6.3 and IBM MQ 8.0.
Now, we are migrating to JBoss EAP 7.1 and in the process we face few issues while deploying the war in the server. The error goes something like this...

```
Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.<<war File Name>>: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.<<war File Name>>: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [com/.../CamelConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route XXXRequestRoute: Route(XXXRequestRoute)[[From[webSphereMQ:queue:<<queue name>> because of Failed to resolve endpoint: webSphereMQ://queue:<<queue name>>?concurrentConsumers=5 due to: No component found with scheme: webSphereMQ

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource [com/.../CamelConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route XXXRequestRoute: Route(XXXRequestRoute)[[From[webSphereMQ:queue:<<queue name>>... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: webSphereMQ://queue:<<queue name>>?concurrentConsumers=5 due to: No component found with scheme: webSphereMQ
```

I was able to google and find some IBM MQ limitation (with JBoss EAP 7.1) in the following location

[Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform > 7.0 > Configuring Messaging > Procedure to Deploy the IBM WebSphere® Resource Adapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuring_messaging/#deploy_the_websphere_mq_resource_adapter)

But this limitation states about IBM MQ 7.5 and not about IBM MQ 8.0.

Could someone help me here to tell me if this limitation applies to IBM MQ 8 as well?

Comment: See if this helps at all [unable to connect from JBoss EAP7 to websphere MQ](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274927)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I have been late in answering.
Infact the webpage link that I posted earlier had the answer.

So here is what we did to get moving!
Section 31.4.1 in the same link as in the question...
[this link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/configuring_messaging/#deploy_the_websphere_mq_resource_adapter)
The specific point of the section is noted here below.

> The deployment of the IBM WebSphere® MQ 7.5 resource adapter does not
>   load the javax.jms.api module for your deployment. It also does not
>   provide support for the new Jave EE 7 annotations like
>   @JMSConnectionFactoryDefinitions, @JMSDestinationDefinition. It is
>   necessary to have the messaging-activemq subsystem in the
>   configuration to enable it. If you do not want the JBoss EAP messaging
>   server to be started, add an empty messaging-activemq subsystem.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
</subsystem>
```

Just by adding the given subsystem tag in the standalone xml, we were able to proceed!

Thanks!

Comment: Link only answers are good.  The links can change.  Better to provide the link and then quote the relevant info from the page in your answer.

Comment: Edited as per your suggestion Josh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which limitation are you referring to?

As to the documentation, you should be using at least version 7.5.0.6 or 8.0.0.6 of the IBM MQ JCA adapter.

JBoss EAP 7.1 does conform to the JCA 1.7 specification.  The IBM MQ 8 JCA is also JCA version 1.7.